# UrlEncode problem in vscode notebook cell

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, urlencode

I am trying to add an URL to jump to another file named in Chinese in the notebook markdown cell with the following code:

```
[测试](./测试.ipynb)
```

But when I click, an error occurs:

```
Unable to open %E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95.ipynb'
Unable to read file 'd:\coding\repos\test\%E6%B568B%E8%AF695.ipynb'(Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'd:\coding\repos\test\%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95.ipynb)
```

[image]

There seems no encoding option that can be set for .ipynb file. (I tried to add a setting.json file in .vscode folder to set encoding, but it failed.) And there is no error when using jupyter-lab. So I think this might be a bug of vscode. I opened an issue in vscode. But before that [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9849) is solved, is there any method I can deal with this?

**Update** Updating to 1.68.1 solves the problem.

Comment: if you show the issue URL users can upvote so the team might look at it sooner

Comment: @rioV8, thanks for your reminder, and the GitHub issue link is already added.

Comment: @yangtzech: Just claiming that it's solve without specification is not the wat stackoverflow works.  People reading your question want to know how it is solved.  The solution is: "Updating to 1.68.1 solves the problem.

Comment: @Luuk: Thanks for your suggestion, and I have added the specification.

Comment: @Luuk: By the way, should I update the question or answer the question about how the problem is solved?

Comment: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking), (This also works when you did not know the answer before asking..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not get it solved in VS Code until VS Code developers dealt with the issue. And Updating to a later release, 1.68.1 solves the problem.